# Run df.merge, df.apply in batches for big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with around 500k rows and need to run several `df.merge`, `df.apply` and requests to the Google Maps API. After applying the changes on the columns I want to write to a `.csv` file.

I've tried to run the code several times but it crashes all the time and takes several hours/days. I believe it is because I'm making too many requests in a short time to the Google Maps API.

I've tested the code up to 1000 lines and it works.

How do I batch the code to run, let's says, 100 rows at a time, and write to the same `.csv`?

Comment: first run code in console/terminal to see error message - to see what is real problem. If you use `try/except` then you could remove it or you have to write error in `except` (don't use `pass` to skip problem). Maybe problem is memory, not `API`. `API` usually doesn't makes problem when you have many requests in short time but it may have limit of requests per hour, per day, etc. But first you have to see if you get error message and what is the real problem

Comment: `read_csv()` has option to read in `chanks` (ie. 100 rows)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use `sklearn.datasets` to demonstrate my logic, since no data was provided.

So, if you need to process your data with small chunks, I'd recommend using the idea below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

df = pd.DataFrame(load_diabetes().data, columns=load_diabetes().feature_names)

df['batch_num'] = df.index // 100 # This creates split by 100 rows

for i in df.batch_num.unique():
    # df[df.batch_num == i] 
    pass
```

The idea is to split your data into `df.index // 100` chunks, by 100 observations each, and access in `for` loop